# Alfresco error : Unable to locate resource resource :nodes children

Tags: rest, alfresco

I'm using Alfresco Community, when I try to get the following adresse :

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/-root-/children

I'm getting a good result without errors
But when using Alfresco One, I'm getting the following error :

> {"error":{"errorKey":"Unable to locate resource resource for :nodes
>   children","statusCode":400,"briefSummary":"05260205 Unable to locate
>   resource resource for :nodes
>   children","stackTrace":"[org.alfresco.rest.framework.core.ResourceLookupDictionary.locateRelationResource(ResourceLookupDictionary.java:89),
>   org.alfresco.rest.framework.core.ResourceLookupDictionary.locateResource(ResourceLookupDictionary.java:114),
>   org.alfresco.rest.framework.webscripts.AbstractResourceWebScript.execute(AbstractResourceWebScript.java:88),
>   org.alfresco.rest.framework.webscripts.ApiWebScript.execute(ApiWebScript.java:152),
>   org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:467),
>   org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:70),
>   org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:656),
>   org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:428),
>   org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:308),
>   org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer.access$001(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:51),
>   org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer$1.doWork(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:106),
>   org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsWork(TenantUtil.java:126),
>   org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsTenant(TenantUtil.java:95),
>   org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer.executeScript(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:102),
>   org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:399),
>   org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:210),
>   org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.TenantWebScriptServlet.service(TenantWebScriptServlet.java:82),
>   org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiWebScriptServlet.service(PublicApiWebScriptServlet.java:60),
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208),
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208),
>   org.alfresco.module.aosmodule.service.ContextRootFilter.doFilter(ContextRootFilter.java:93),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208),
>   org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:75),
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1814.invoke(Unknown Source),
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source),
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source),
>   org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:132),
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172),
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204),
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy320.doFilter(Unknown Source),
>   org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:89),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208),
>   org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:68),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122),
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170),
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103),
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950),
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116),
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421),
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074), org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611),
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466),
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455),
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source),
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source),
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61),
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source)]","descriptionURL":"http://developer.alfresco.com/ErrorsExplained.html#Unable
>   to locate resource resource for :nodes children"}}

Does anyone knows what is going wrong please ?
Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay my bad, found out that /nodes/-root-/children came out with the v5.2 .. my Alfresco One is still in 5.1 ...

Answer (score 0):

Even you can try node.childByNamePath() , that is a good way to get child nodes of given node.